# Pay with Paytm in React native Causing issue

Tags: react-native, payment, paytm

I am trying to integrate the pament using paytm in my react-native app. I am getting "Abandoned transaction" error. 
I am sending following JSON:-

```
CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID="1850"
CHANNEL_ID: "WAP"
CHECKSUMHASH: "************************"
CUST_ID: "271"
EMAIL: "abc@gmail.com"
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail"
MID: "**********"
MOBILE_NO: "**********"
ORDER_ID: "1850"
TXN_AMOUNT: "10.00"
WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING"
mode: "Staging"
```

I am using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/@philly25/react-native-paytm" module. Please help me out. If anyone has integrate the same, Please tell us with steps.

Comment: It can be anything that causes this error. Try to add more logs.

Comment: Yes, found the issue, The error was WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING" it should be WEBSITE: "WEBSTAGING"

Comment: @Jyoti can you please share the react native code here as I am facing the same issue?

Comment: @Harshit Do you facing checksum mismatching issue

Comment: @Jyoti I dont know I am unable to open paytm on onpress of button. After clicking a white screen appears and then I am redirected to my app.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal There must be an error while you are creating your checksum at server

Comment: @Jyoti server code is as it is provided by paytm only, i am only calling with orderId. Please suggest, I am getting same error as Harshit